# How to make automatic setter and getter using annotation in java?

Tags: java, interface, annotations

It's very tough to add getter and setter method for all objects is there any easy way to do that? can we create an interface or annotation for that?

`private String name;
public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
public String getName() {return name;}`

I wish something like `@GetterSetter private String name;`

I know that Eclipse and IDEA will generate easily what I want my code looks clean i don't want to make my number of lines x*5 more.

Comment: If you're using an IDE you can generate getters and setters for all fields automatically

Comment: That makes my code very big and i don't like lot of lines of code :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use inteliJ special features or external libraries you must write your own annotation's processor which will process example setter and getter's annotations(for example: @Get, @Set).

But when defining the two annotations you must remember about the special type of metaannotation:
    `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`

because w/o this RetentionPolicy your getter's and setter's annotation won't be available in final program !

Annotation processor you write using reflection on your two annotations.

If you don't want to write this processor you can use even apt from default JDK.

Cheers, gjm

Answer (score 5):

You can try lombok library. By using this you can avoid of writing getter, setter, hashCode, toString methods. A typical example look likes below.

```
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@EqualsAndHashCode()
@ToString
public class Employee {
 @Getter @Setter private int id;
 @Getter @Setter private String firstName;
 @Getter @Setter private String lastName;
 @Getter @Setter private int age;
}
```

You can refer
https://projectlombok.org/

For examples refer this [link](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/08/project-lombok.html)

Comment: but your IDE will requrie plugin for lombok to avoid compilation issues

Answer (score 1):

If your using intelliJ, you can use keyboard shortcuts, its not that hard.
Just Alt+ insert, select getter and setter and then youre done!